# ?How to add new router dependencies to Angular2 project

Tags: angular, angular-new-router

I've followed the starter app at: 'Learn in 5 mins' from https://angular.io/.  I want to start trying to use the 'new' router, but when I do a:

```
import {...} from 'angular2/router';
```

I get a:

```
 error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'angular2/router'.
```

Can I add this dependency in a manner similar to how angular2 was installed.  Namely, similar to:

```
tsd query angular2 --action install
```

Answer (score 1):

`tsd install` will only add the type definition files used by TypeScript.

I don't believe the 5 minute demo is setup for using the router yet. If you need a quick fix, add a link to the router code `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/router.dev.js"></script>` with a matching version number.

Perhaps a better alternative would be using [one of the many angular 2 boilerplates](http://www.tryangular2.com/category/Boilerplate) out there. There isn't much sense in approaching the setup learning curve as it will be greatly simplified after Angular leaves alpha.

Comment: The quick fix link seems to work - at least the Console errors are gone.

Answer (score 1):

you get this error because angular2/router module is not defiend in your `tsd.d.ts` file. you can get out from this error by these methods.

1 command for install typings and add as your refference in the tsd.d.ts file.

```
tsd install angular2/router --save
```

2. or you can add link to the router code

   <`script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.37/router.dev.js"></script>`

i hope by following this you get your fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need angular router definition. I fix the problem using [ng2.d.ts](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/typings/_custom/ng2.d.ts)
from [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter)

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 2.0 alpha 30 it's easier to use the router
Here is an example of how to use it: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Answer (score 0):

The router is contained in its own separate package

```
tsd install angular2/router --save
```

To import use:

```
import { 
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    RouteConfig,
} from 'angular2/router';
```

`ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` gets added to your `@View.directives` property. It includes the `RouterLink` and `RouterOutlet` classes.

`RouteConfig` is required to add a `@RouteConfig` decorator to your component.

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is required to bootstrap your router. It includes the RouteConfig (ie your defined routes) and sets `PathLocationStrategy` as your default `LocationStrategy`.

Ex.

```
bootstrap(App, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]);
```